# happybase uninterruptly not working with hbase

Tags: python, hbase, happybase

i'm using happybase to pass data from twitter to my hbase setup,Initially its working fine,i can create connection with hbase and table also,but now i cant able to put,scan,delete any data in hbase through happybase, by script & python prompt,

```
>>> import happybase
>>> cn = happybase.Connection('localhost')
>>> v = cn.table('test')
>>> <happybase.table.Table name='test'>
>>> v
>>> <happybase.table.Table name='test'>
>>> n = v.scan(row_prefix='0001')
>>> for key,data in n:
...   print key,data
```

When i try put or scan data, system doesn't do anything only loading upto 8 hours

Please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the right 'compat' argument to `happybase.Connection`? Not doing so may result in stalled connections. This is not something HappyBase can do anything about, unfortunately. See the explicit note/warning about this issue in the user guide at http://happybase.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user.html#establishing-a-connection